# How to create a nginx rule to block the scan of a webserver?

Tags: logging, nginx

I just found that someone was trying to scan my webserver to hack user's password.
How can I block this kind of access?

```
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "174.44.72.5"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "106.4.59.6"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "14.17.60.6"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "220.44.43.6"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "174.44.72.6"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "106.4.59.7"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "220.44.43.7"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "14.17.60.7"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "174.44.72.7"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "106.4.59.8"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:01 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "220.44.43.8"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "14.17.60.8"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "174.44.72.8"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "220.44.43.9"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "106.4.59.9"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "174.44.72.9"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "14.17.60.9"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "220.44.43.10"
171.12.148.114 - - [14/Oct/2013:09:48:02 +0800] "POST /forummember.php?mod=logging&action=login&loginsubmit=yes&loginhash=&inajax=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)" "106.4.59.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of requests and connections by IP, with the modules:

[ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) or [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html)

Also advise the use of naxsi: https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi

NAXSI means Nginx Anti Xss & Sql Injection.